# What is the proper way to force users to update Metro Applications?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

What is the proper way to force users to update Metro Applications?

An example:
Let's say we have a metro style (Windows 8) application named "xyz".
We deployed "xyz" to Windows store. One week later we found a huge bug on the payment page.
So we should force the user to update the xyz application to new version.
What is the best practice for that? Does Microsoft provide a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't force a user to update an app as such, but you do have some options...

1. The windows store will automatically let the user know that there is
   an update available.   This behaviour comes for free and you don't need to code for it.
2. You can make a "current version number" available via the web (maybe just as a static XML file).  Then you can get your app to check this number against an internal variable.  If the currently installed version is older than the updated version then you could display a "Please visit the store to upgrade" type message instead of the main app UI.

Neither of these options mean that your app is forcing an upgrade, but they are making the user aware that an update is available, and that functionality may be impacted if they don't upgrade.

Comment: You can also use the version number to do a a real page navigation in your application, and move to a local file in your package that blocks all the functionality of your application, and lets the user link direct to the store update page. But this is a very poor experience.

Also, be aware that you would need to poll this version file on the internet periodically -- your app may be suspended for days/weeks depending on other system pressures, so doing it only in startup may not be the experience you are looking for.

Comment: blocking of functionality might be a good choice at time but it only useful if the user actually understand why the function is blocked. been encountering issue where users are still several version behind and met with crashes in which those are fixed in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You may find what you are looking for in 
Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp
With this you can take the user to the app store page from a dialog stating that an update must be performed.